# Multiple Notification and Intent issue

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, alarmmanager, statusbar

I am developing an application where the user may schedule training date and time. The user may schedule multiple training dates and times while using the application. Say for example the user will schedule two training, TR1 and TR2. When the TR1 date and time matches, a notification will be sent to the user and onclicking the notification the user will be directed to the Training Activity. The same will happen for TR2 on reaching the date and time of the training.

For scheduling the notifications, I am using the **AlarmManager**. The problem which I am facing is that, if I schedule multiple training, I am getting notified for only the last one.

The **activity** for **generating the notifications**:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
    //objects for use
    DateFormat fmtDateAndTime=DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
      TextView dateAndTimeLabel;
      Calendar dateAndTime=Calendar.getInstance();
      ImageView confirm;
      String dateTime;

      EditText duration;

      //Alarm manager object for notification
      AlarmManager am;


      //notification date and time
      int hour;
      int minute;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings_portrait);
        duration=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.duration_editText);
        dateAndTimeLabel=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeTxt);

        updateLabel();
        updateNotification();
        am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

     // On Click Confirm

            confirm=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.confirm_imageView);
            confirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getDateTime();

                   setOneTimeAlarm();
                }
            });

      }
      //date picker
      public void chooseDate(View v) {
        new DatePickerDialog(SettingsActivity.this, d,
                              dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                              dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                              dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
          .show();
      }
      //time picker
      public void chooseTime(View v) {
        new TimePickerDialog(SettingsActivity.this, t,
                              dateAndTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                              dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                              true)
          .show();
      }

      private void updateLabel() {
        dateAndTimeLabel.setText(fmtDateAndTime
                                  .format(dateAndTime.getTime()));
      }

      DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
          dateAndTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
          dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
          dateAndTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
          updateLabel();
          updateNotification();
        }
      };

      TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                              int minute) {
          dateAndTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
          dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
          updateLabel();
          updateNotification();

        }
      };  




   // Notification Function
//      private void Notification(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage)
//      {
//          NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
//          Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Training Scheduled!", System.currentTimeMillis());
//          //on click notification goto dinnerden activity
//          Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
//          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
//   
//          notification.setLatestEventInfo(SettingsActivity.this, notificationTitle, notificationMessage, pendingIntent);
//          notificationManager.notify(10001, notification);
//      }
      //getting date time from textview
      void getDateTime()
      {
         dateTime= dateAndTimeLabel.getText().toString()+" Duration HRS: "+duration.getText().toString();

         makeAToast(dateTime);
         //Notification("Training Scheduled at:",dateTime);

      }

      void updateNotification()
      {
          hour= dateAndTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
          minute=dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
      }



      public void setOneTimeAlarm() {

        // the time set
         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
//          hour= dateAndTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
//          minute=dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        // int hour= dateAndTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        // int minute=dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
         // noon tomorrow
         //calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
         calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
         calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
         calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);





      Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
      am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
       calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
     }

     public void setRepeatingAlarm() {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
      am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
        (5 * 1000), pendingIntent);
     }








      public void makeAToast(String str) {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(1000000);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

The **class** for **creating the notifications**:

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

     NotificationManager nm;

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      nm = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      CharSequence from = "Scheduled Training";
      CharSequence message = "Please attend the scheduled training";
     // Intent welcomeIntent = new Intent(context, CustomAlarm.class);
      PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        new Intent(), 0);
      Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        "Crazy About Android...", System.currentTimeMillis());
      notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
      nm.notify(1, notif);
     }
    }
```

The **layout** for the **activity**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="488dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/confirm_imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/schedule_button" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeTxt"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
                android:text="@string/time_show" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/timeBtn"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/timeTxt"
                android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
                android:onClick="chooseTime"
                android:text="@string/time" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dateBtn"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/timeBtn"
                android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
                android:onClick="chooseDate"
                android:text="@string/date" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/duration_editText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/dateBtn"
                android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/duration_hint"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/duration_textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/duration_editText"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/duration_editText"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/duration"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Part of **manifest.xml**:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name="com.project.nuroq.android.app.TimeAlarm" />
```

I want to fire the notifications at particular time(implemented) and dates(yet to implement) which is not happening now. The last is only getting fired!

Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use different ID for each notification. If, as you do, all would use the same ID value, then, according to [notify() docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29), previous one gets replaced with new one:

> Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. If a notification
>   with the same id has already been posted by your application and has
>   not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.